# IIS 6.0 SMTP NDR SPAM Backscatter

Tags: iis-6, smtp, amazon-ec2

We have a IIS 6.0 server on AWS EC2 that is receiving emails and forwarding onto another IIS box, we are inadvertently sending NDR emails via the SMTP service to the forged From: header with the spam attached.

A few quick questions regarding IIS 6.0 SMTP

1. From reading we don't see a was to stop NDRs (this is by design to meet RFC requirements)
2. As we accept all emails sent to our address and process off line on a seperate machine can someone advise why NDR's are been delivered in the first place? Is there some other loophole they are using to force the SMTP server to generate Delayed and Non Delivery Reports?

Also can anyone recommend software that can stop this type of attack. e.g. Toriss, ORF from Vamsoft

Answer (score 0):

You have to use SPF on the receiving machine so it does not accept mails with forged reverse-paths. There is no way to really fix the issue later in the mail server chain. (Note that the SMTP reverse path is not necessarily the same as the address in the From header, for example they always differ in list mails. If IIS does send bounce mails to the From address instead of the reverse-path then it is horribly broken.) If IIS does not know SPF, then you have to use a different mail server or an SMTP proxy.